# Open multiple bottom sheet - stacked one above another using $mdBottomSheet

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

am using Angularjs $mdBottomSheet to open bottom sheet above app. I can open one bottom sheet but when tried to open another, old one is replaced by new one or overlapped. I want to show bottom sheet as stacked in case of multiple bottom sheet open. see this image. there are multiple message I want to show in bottom. Is it possible through $mdBottomSheet. What are alternatives.

[stackedmessagesonbottomofapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0iKo.png)

```
      $mdBottomSheet.show({
                    templateUrl: 'templatefolder/xyz.html',                       
                    clickOutsideToClose: false,
                    escapeToClose: false,                    
                    controller: MessageController
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    
                });
```

Comment: Please include your code as formatted text in the question. Also, if you have any errors include them as well.

Comment: included code which used in showing messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS Material implements [Modal Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-modal-bottom-sheets) from the Material Design Spec. This design does not allow for multiple, stacked bottom sheets to be open at one time.

Additionally, for tablets or desktop screens the spec defines a number of alternatives to consider
[image: alternatives to bottom sheets]

If you want to create a custom implementation of panels that can stack, then I would suggest that you investigate our more flexible [$mdPanel service](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/panel).

Comment: I checked this Panel service  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/panel , but it does not say anything about stacking , if you can can you please share some link where I can get more info for stacking panel or some other component who can support stacking. Thanks

Comment: In $mdPanel Service https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdPanel I did not see anything here related to support for expand and collapse panel. I guess expanding and collapsing is supported. Please let me know any relevant document describing that.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/type/MdPanelAnimation details some of the animation options. The `SLIDE` option could potentially be used for expanding and collapsing. But you could use use a custom cssClass with `.withAnimation()` to run your custom animations. There is no built in support for stacking, but it's not clear that `$mdPanel` wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks for response and help, one more question, currently our plan is to use $mdDialog for stacked messages. I guess stacking can be done for dialog box. One thing I want to know, is it possible to add support for collapse/expand if I use $mdDialog to create dialog box? Or to use collapse/expand feature it is must to use $mdPanel? Please provide your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: $mdDialog only supports animating the dialog to/from different parts of the screen when it opens/closes. It doesn't support any kind of expand/collapse or custom animations like $mdPanel. $mdDialog only supports the `onComplete` callback so that you can trigger/finish other animations after the dialog closes.